# How do I iterate over a column in a Pandas.DataFrame and append the result of a function to the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, datetime

I have a `Pandas.DataFrame` generated via the following CSV:

```
Category,Brand,Product Name,Price,Expiration Date, Package ID,Quantity
Cat1,Brand1,Product1,$1000,07/14/2020,XXXXXX,34
```

I am trying to append a column to the CSV with an integer in each row corresponding to how soon the expiration date is (`4` indicates greater than 6 months, `3` indicates between 3 and 6 months, etc).

My issue is that when trying to convert the `Expiration Date` column to datetime (using `pandas.to_datetime(df['Expiration Date'])`) and then apply my `classify_expiration()` function, the types either do not match what the function indicates or it attempts to apply the function to `index 0` which is what I believe to be the header (and thus does not match the `%m/%d/%Y` format). I have tried converting the column to datetime within the classification function, as well as outside of it before the `.apply()` call. I have also tried using `timedelta` to compare the expiration dates to today's current date, but it does not work with `datetime.date.today()`.

Here is the first way I tried it:

```py
def classify_expiration(row):    
    one_week = timedelta(weeks=1, days=0, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0)

    if ((one_week * 0) <= (date.today() - row['Expiration Date']) <= (one_week * 4)):
        return 4
```

This way gives me errors relating to types being incorrect at `index 0` or not being able to apply the function to a Series.

Here is what I just tried which gives me an `AssertionError`:

```py
def days_between(date1, date2):
    """Calculates the number of days between two dates

    Keyword arguments:
    date1 -- The first date in the subtraction.
    date2 -- The second date in the subtraction.
    """
    date1 = datetime.strptime(date1, '%m/%d/%Y')
    date2 = datetime.strptime(date2, '%m/%d/%Y')
    return abs((date2 - date1).days)


def classify_expiration(row):
    """Calculate days/weeks to expiration. Assign quartile based on value.

    Keyword arguments:
    row -- row in a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object. e.g. `df['A']`
    """

    date_today = datetime.strptime(
        date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')

    if (days_between(row, date_today) <= 30):
        return 4
    if (31 <= days_between(row, date_today) <= 90):
        return 3
    if (91 <= days_between(row, date_today) <= 120):
        return 2
    if (days_between(row, date_today) >= 121):
        return 1
```

Here is where I try to apply the function:

```py
# Convert column to `datetime` if its current type is str
pd.to_datetime(product_sales['Expiration Date'])

# Applying the `classify_expiration()` function
product_sales['Expiration Quartile'] = product_sales.apply(
    lambda row: classify_expiration(row), axis=1
)
```

I expect the function to append a new column to the DataFrame which contains the generated quartile for the expiration date in each row. I will get errors which range from `AssertionError`, `argument 1 must be str, not Series`, and various other errors relating to `index 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove converting to datetimes in `days_between` function if assign back `product_sales['Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(product_sales['Expiration Date'])` and then use `product_sales['Expiration Date'].apply(classify_expiration)` for loop by scalars:

```
def days_between(date1, date2):
    """Calculates the number of days between two dates

    Keyword arguments:
    date1 -- The first date in the subtraction.
    date2 -- The second date in the subtraction.
    """
    return abs((date2 - date1).days)


product_sales['Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(product_sales['Expiration Date'])

product_sales['Expiration Quartile'] = (product_sales['Expiration Date']
                                               .apply(classify_expiration))
print (product_sales)
  Category   Brand Product Name  Price Expiration Date Package ID  Quantity  \
0     Cat1  Brand1     Product1  $1000      2020-07-14     XXXXXX        34   

   Expiration Quartile  
0                    1
```

Pandas has special functions for binnig, so instead your function is possible use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
product_sales['Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(product_sales['Expiration Date'])

product_sales['Expiration Quartile'] = (product_sales['Expiration Date']
                                             .apply(classify_expiration))

s = product_sales['Expiration Date'].sub(pd.to_datetime('today').floor('d')).dt.days

product_sales['Expiration Quartile1'] = pd.cut(s, 
                                               bins=[0, 30, 90,120, np.inf], 
                                               labels=[4,3,2,1])
print (product_sales)
  Category   Brand Product Name  Price Expiration Date Package ID  Quantity  \
0     Cat1  Brand1     Product1  $1000      2020-07-14     XXXXXX        34   
1     Cat1  Brand1     Product1  $1000      2020-01-13     XXXXXX        34   
2     Cat1  Brand1     Product1  $1000      2019-11-01     XXXXXX        34   
3     Cat1  Brand1     Product1  $1000      2020-01-15     XXXXXX        34   

   Expiration Quartile Expiration Quartile1  
0                    1                    1  
1                    3                    3  
2                    4                    4  
3                    2                    2
```